# Frustrated with Python's sorted Built-in (with range and lambda as key)

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, lambda

I encountered something that makes no sense to me. See this use of `sorted` with `range` and `lambda`:

```
sorted(range(-5, 6), key=lambda x: x * x)
```

Which outputs this in the Python shell:

```
[0, -1, 1, -2, 2, -3, 3, -4, 4, -5, 5]
```

Now, for the life of me, I don't get this! I've been playing around with `sorted`, `lambda`, and `range`, and it doesn't make sense. For example, if you run the `range` bit in a for loop, you get something like this:

```
>>> for i in range(-5, 6):
...     print(i)
-5
-4
...
0
...
4
5
```

And the `lambda` bit:

```
>>> (lambda x: x * x)(-5)
25
```

But putting it all together... I don't understand how using the `key` this way makes the order independent of the sign.

But this makes sense to me:

```
>>> sorted(range(-5, 6), key=lambda x: abs(x))
[0, -1, 1, -2, 2, -3, 3, -4, 4, -5, 5]
```

Can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: For the purposes of a sorting key, squaring a number and taking it's absolute value are the same thing. What exactly is it that you don't get? Because squaring a number makes every (real) number positive. It has the same effect, in that sense, as taking the absolute value.

Comment: Why do you think `x^2` and `abs(x)` would sort differently?

Comment: `n^2 == (-n)^2`

Comment: I suspect lambda is really a distraction.

Comment: @Stephen Rauch: I think I'm getting confused with the fact that `(-5)^2` is `25`... whereas `abs(-5)` is `5`...

Comment: @nicorellius well, for every real number x, (x)^2 == (-x)^2. Think of the graph of a parabola, it's a mirror image across the y - axis... Or perhaps:(-x)^2 == (-x)*(-x) == (-1*x)(-1*x) == (-1)(-1)(x)(x) == (1)(x)(x) == (x)^2 ... this really is more of a math question. again, just [look at the graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2)

Comment: Or maybe you'll find `sorted((x*x, x) for x in range(-5, 6))` illuminating

Comment: Thanks for the comments... I understand all the math behind this. That's not the problem. The problem I'm having is the `key` argument. It's meant to act on the items in the list for comparison in the sort, right?. So `abs` says sort these but ignore the sign. Or, `str.lower`, makes the items lowercase for sorting purposes. But the `x * x` seems like it should multiply something, but it's just switching the sign.

Comment: I believe you were expecting `[0, 1, 1, 4, 4, 9, 9, 16, 16, 25, 25]` as your output , the key function is just used to extract a comparison key but do not alter the input list in the first place, so you would get the output of `range(-5, 6) sorted based on the key `(x*x)` in this case.

Comment: @nicorellius it *is* multiplying something, it's multiplying the number  by itself, i.e. squaring it... note, neither `abs` nor `lambda x: x*x` **switch** signs, they make *everything positive*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: of course, my mistake. After re-reading what I wrote, I wish I could edit it... Yes, `abs` makes everything positive. Thanks for your comments. They were helpful in getting me to the point of understanding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's go through this step by step:

- The sequence you're sorting is `range(-5, 6)`, which is `[-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.
- The elements of this sequence with their corresponding keys are:

  ```
    x | x * x
  ----|-------
   -5 | 25
   -4 | 16
   -3 |  9
   -2 |  4
   -1 |  1
    0 |  0
    1 |  1
    2 |  4
    3 |  9
    4 | 16
    5 | 25
  ```
- Now let's sort this table by key:

  ```
           x | x * x
  -----------|-------
           0 |  0
    -1 and 1 |  1
    -2 and 2 |  4
    -3 and 3 |  9
    -4 and 4 | 16
    -5 and 5 | 25
  ```

  This means that the output of `sorted()` will be `0`, then `-1` and `1` in some order, then `-2` and `2` in some order, etc.  [`sorted()` performs a stable sort](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted), so any input elements with the same key will be output in the same order that they appear in the input; since the negatives occur before the positives in `range(-5, 6)`, this means that `sorted()` will output `-1` before `1`, `-2` before `2`, etc.
- Thus, the final output is `[0, -1, 1, -2, 2, -3, 3, -4, 4, -5, 5]`.

Comment: This is great.  A key line from the documentation I find is this: *[The value of the key parameter should be a function that takes a single argument and returns a key to use for sorting purposes.](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions)*  So in a way it's like creating an ordered dictionary with keys sorted based on returned values from the function (`x*x`), and `sorted()`return only the values in order from this dictionary as a list.  This makes a lot of sense to me.

Comment: Thanks for this answer... I'm starting to see how this works. With your second bullet, if you use the `x * x` column as the sorting order, going out from the middle or the zero, you get `0, 1, 1, . . . 25, 25` (like @Sanju commented above). If you apply this to the column from the `range(-5, 6)`, you get `0, -1 or 1, -2 or 2, . . . -5 or 5`. From here it's a matter of the rule Python follows, eg, `sorted()` outputting `-1` before `1` and you're done! Thanks! This helped a lot.

Comment: @Idlehands or, really, it might be better to think of sorting a list of pairs of the form `(keyfunc(x), x)`, i.e. the "schwartzian transform" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform

Comment: @nicorellius The reason -1 comes before 1 is because python's sorting algorithm (tim sort I believe) is [stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability). That is, two otherwise equal elements (according  to the key) will have their order maintained. Ergo, -1 comes before 1 because they have equal keys and -1 came before 1 in the original input